# Search/Filter Dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm following this guide to create **[Search/Filter Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter)**.

*But I have this method '`allNameMuseums()`', that returns an array of names (for example :*

```
array = ["Jack", "Paul", "George"]
```

My JS code :

```
async function allNameMuseums() {
        let nomeFile = "dati_musei_infovis.csv";
        let data3 = await d3.dsv(";", nomeFile, function (d) {
            return {
                Museo: d.Museo,
                Ingresso: d.Ingresso,
                Anno: d.Anno,
                Mese: d.Mese,
                Visitatori: d.Visitatori
            };
        });
        return filtraggioNomeMuseo(data3);
};

function filtraggioNomeMuseo(data) {
        array_filtrato = [];
        var map = {};
        //var visitatori = 0;
        for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (!(array_filtrato.includes(data[i].Museo))) {
                array_filtrato.push(data[i].Museo)
            }
        }
        return array_filtrato;
}
```

I want to put these names instead of About, Base, Blog etc...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're talking about without visiting that site. Currently your code appears to be retrieving data from a file by way of d3. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the returned array and append the names as anchors to the dropdown like :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item){
     document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a href="'+item+'">'+item+'</a>';
  })
});
```

**NOTE:** Put your code inside `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to make sure all the DOM elements are loaded before executing your code/

**Working sample:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item) {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a href="' + item + '">' + item + '</a>';
  })
});


function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function allNameMuseums() {
  return ["Jack", "Paul", "George"];
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for Danny ?